# Howto hide the top bars in Chrome?

Tags: chrome-for-android

I'm on Android11, and using Chrome v96.

Although editing this on a huge (2208x1768) screen, the screen estate is eaten up by chrome's tab bar and url entry bar:

[image]

So the content area is very thin, can I hide those components in Chrome?

To avoid misreading I circled here the areas to be hidden:

[image]

In some rare cases, it auto-hides, but for example when posting to StackExchange, it doesn't.

NOT in rare cases: it always autohides when scrolling downwards, but there is one excluded case: when you are inputting text to an HTML input field.
During edit, it's not being hidden.

So, how can I hide the top bar even during text edition?

Comment: I've been using Chrome for Android for a long time and AFAIK, it's not possible.

Comment: In Chrome the address bar can be hidden unless an editable field is selected. In Firefox you can hide the address bar independently of the selection.